# Delete customer from dashboard statistics chart | OpenCart2.X

Tags: charts, dashboard, opencart2.x

As title says, I need to delete the customer from the chart in the dashboard. Hence, keeping only the orders in the chart.

How can I do it ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the opencart 2.0.2.0, modify 'admin\view\template\dashboard\chart.tpl' as below:

Replace the line

```
$.plot('#chart-sale', [json['order'], json['customer']], option);
```

with

```
$.plot('#chart-sale', [json['order']], option);
```